# Controlling frequency of a Slayer exciter circuit for plasma magnetism tests

Tags: microcontroller, power-supply, transistors, transformer, tesla-coil

I want to build a Slayer exciter circuit from a 48 volts 50 ampere power supply.

I have the necessary transistor, but I want to be able to tune the frequency of the circuit with a Raspberry Pi and achieve a high voltage controlled from 1kV to 5kV. It is to ionize, inductively, a low vacuum glass chamber so I can trap the plasma created inside of it (much easier than electric bombardment.) I want to test out the magnetism of the plasma at various frequencies (from 50 Hz all the way to 13.56MHz.)

Is there a way for me to control the frequency of this circuit through digital means or without having to buy a bunch of components, without having to change coils and whatnot? If it isn't possible with this circuit to change the frequency without necessarily having to change the coils (which I could do, but it would be a tad annoying) is there another circuit for tuneable HF,HV AC digitally?

[image: This is the circuit I saw and had in mind]

Comment: Please post a picture into the body of your question of your proposed schematic.

Comment: @Andyaka added.

Comment: The tuning is set by the output coil's parasitic capacitance. It's a fairly uncontrollable circuit. Designing a HT power supply that produces AC at a frequency range as low as 50 Hz and can be extended up to the MHz is certainly non-trivial and could cost many thousands of £/$ to design/build.

Comment: I wouldn't add the topload to my system, I would just use the wire to make a solenoid around a glass low vacuum tube. But to clarify, you are saying that this circuit isnt able to be tuned to a frequency digitally? Or through some other means that doesnt require a ton of electrical components?

Comment: Across such a vast frequency range, yes, that is what I'm saying.

Comment: Just getting a single transformer to work over the range of 50 Hz to 14 MHz is non-trivial.

Comment: what about from the khz range to mhz range?